# "unable to open debugger attach fifo" running Openmpi using cygwin

Tags: windows, cygwin, mpi, openmpi

I installed OpenMPI cygwin packages on Windows10.

When I test mpiexec(mpirun as well), it keeps showing an error message "unable to open debugger attach fifo".

```
$ mpifort Console1.f90

$ mpiexec -np 3 ./a
 Hello,world! :from           3 processes
 I am process            2
 I am process            1
[DESKTOP-72E341K:00859] [[46244,0],0] unable to open debugger attach fifo
```

I did the same test on two Windows10 computers after installing the OpenMPI cygwin packages in the same way, but the error message comes up on both computers.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?
I put a list of installed packages just in case.

```
Cygwin Package Information
Package                    Version                         Status
_autorebase                001007-1                        OK
alternatives               1.3.30c-10                      OK
base-cygwin                3.8-1                           OK
base-files                 4.3-2                           OK
bash                       4.4.12-3                        OK
binutils                   2.35.2-1                        OK
bzip2                      1.0.8-1                         OK
ca-certificates            2.40-1                          OK
cmake                      3.20.0-1                        OK
coreutils                  8.26-2                          OK
crypto-policies            20190218-1                      OK
csih                       0.9.11-1                        OK
cygrunsrv                  1.62-1                          OK
cygutils                   1.4.16-2                        OK
cygwin                     3.2.0-1                         OK
cygwin-debuginfo           3.2.0-1                         OK
cygwin-devel               3.2.0-1                         OK
dash                       0.5.9.1-1                       OK
diffutils                  3.5-2                           OK
editrights                 1.03-1                          OK
file                       5.39-1                          OK
findutils                  4.6.0-1                         OK
gawk                       5.1.0-1                         OK
gcc-core                   10.2.0-1                        OK
gcc-fortran                10.2.0-1                        OK
gcc-g++                    10.2.0-1                        OK
gdb                        9.2-1                           OK
getent                     2.18.90-4                       OK
git                        2.31.1-1                        OK
gnupg                      1.4.23-1                        OK
grep                       3.0-2                           OK
groff                      1.22.4-1                        OK
gzip                       1.8-1                           OK
hostname                   3.13-1                          OK
info                       6.7-1                           OK
ipc-utils                  1.0-1                           OK
less                       563-1                           OK
libarchive13               3.5.1-1                         OK
libargp                    20110921-3                      OK
libassuan0                 2.5.3-1                         OK
libatomic1                 10.2.0-1                        OK
libattr1                   2.4.48-2                        OK
libblkid1                  2.33.1-2                        OK
libboost_regex1.66         1.66.0-1                        OK
libbrotlicommon1           1.0.9-1                         OK
libbrotlidec1              1.0.9-1                         OK
libbz2_1                   1.0.8-1                         OK
libcares2                  1.14.0-1                        OK
libcbor                    0.5.0-1                         OK
libcom_err2                1.44.5-1                        OK
libcrypt2                  4.4.4-1                         OK
libcurl4                   7.76.0-1                        OK
libdb5.3                   5.3.28-2                        OK
libedit0                   20130712-1                      OK
libevent-devel             2.0.22-1                        OK
libevent2.0_5              2.0.22-1                        OK
libexpat1                  2.2.6-1                         OK
libfdisk1                  2.33.1-2                        OK
libffi6                    3.2.1-1                         OK
libfido2                   1.5.0-1                         OK
libgc1                     8.0.4-1                         OK
libgcc1                    10.2.0-1                        OK
libgdbm6                   1.18.1-1                        OK
libgdbm_compat4            1.18.1-1                        OK
libgfortran5               10.2.0-1                        OK
libgmp10                   6.2.1-1                         OK
libgnutls30                3.6.9-1                         OK
libgomp1                   10.2.0-1                        OK
libgpg-error0              1.37-1                          OK
libgpgme11                 1.9.0-1                         OK
libgssapi_krb5_2           1.15.2-2                        OK
libguile2.2_1              2.2.7-1                         OK
libhogweed4                3.4.1-1                         OK
libhwloc-devel             2.0.3-1                         OK
libhwloc15                 2.0.3-1                         OK
libiconv                   1.16-2                          OK
libiconv2                  1.16-2                          OK
libicu61                   61.1-1                          OK
libidn2_0                  2.2.0-1                         OK
libintl8                   0.19.8.1-2                      OK
libisl22                   0.22.1-2                        OK
libjsoncpp24               1.9.4-1                         OK
libk5crypto3               1.15.2-2                        OK
libkrb5_3                  1.15.2-2                        OK
libkrb5support0            1.15.2-2                        OK
libltdl7                   2.4.6-7                         OK
liblz4_1                   1.7.5-1                         OK
liblzma5                   5.2.4-1                         OK
liblzo2_2                  2.10-2                          OK
libmetalink3               0.1.2-1                         OK
libmpc3                    1.2.1-1                         OK
libmpfr6                   4.1.0-1                         OK
libncursesw10              6.1-1.20190727                  OK
libnettle6                 3.4.1-1                         OK
libnghttp2_14              1.37.0-1                        OK
libopenldap2_4_2           2.4.58-1                        OK
libopenmpi-devel           4.1.0-1                         OK
libopenmpi12               1.10.7-1                        OK
libopenmpi40               4.1.0-1                         OK
libopenmpicxx1             1.10.7-1                        OK
libopenmpifh40             4.1.0-1                         OK
libopenmpiusef08_40        4.1.0-1                         OK
libopenmpiusetkr40         4.1.0-1                         OK
libp11-kit0                0.23.20-1                       OK
libpcre1                   8.44-2                          OK
libpcre2_8_0               10.36-1                         OK
libpipeline1               1.5.3-1                         OK
libpkgconf3                1.6.3-1                         OK
libpopt-common             1.18-1                          OK
libpopt0                   1.18-1                          OK
libpsl5                    0.21.0-1                        OK
libquadmath0               10.2.0-1                        OK
libreadline7               7.0.3-3                         OK
librhash0                  1.4.0-1                         OK
libsasl2_3                 2.1.27-1                        OK
libsigsegv2                2.10-2                          OK
libsmartcols1              2.33.1-2                        OK
libsource-highlight-common 3.1.8-6                         OK
libsource-highlight4       3.1.8-6                         OK
libsqlite3_0               3.34.0-1                        OK
libssh2_1                  1.7.0-1                         OK
libssl1.0                  1.0.2t-1                        OK
libssl1.1                  1.1.1f-1                        OK
libstdc++6                 10.2.0-1                        OK
libtasn1_6                 4.14-1                          OK
libunistring2              0.9.10-1                        OK
libuuid-devel              2.33.1-2                        OK
libuuid1                   2.33.1-2                        OK
libuv1                     1.41.0-1                        OK
libxml2                    2.9.10-2                        OK
libxml2-devel              2.9.10-2                        OK
libzstd1                   1.4.9-1                         OK
login                      1.13-1                          OK
lynx                       2.8.7-1                         OK
make                       4.3-1                           OK
man-db                     2.9.4-1                         OK
mintty                     3.4.7-1                         OK
ncurses                    6.1-1.20190727                  OK
openmpi                    4.1.0-1                         OK
openmpi-debuginfo          4.1.0-1                         OK
openssh                    8.5p1-1                         OK
openssl                    1.1.1f-1                        OK
p11-kit                    0.23.20-1                       OK
p11-kit-trust              0.23.20-1                       OK
patch                      2.7.4-1                         OK
patchutils                 0.3.4-1                         OK
perl                       5.32.1-1                        OK
perl-Error                 0.17029-2                       OK
perl-Scalar-List-Utils     1.56-1                          OK
perl-TermReadKey           2.38-3                          OK
perl_autorebase            5.32.1-1                        OK
perl_base                  5.32.1-1                        OK
pkg-config                 1.6.3-1                         OK
pkgconf                    1.6.3-1                         OK
publicsuffix-list-dafsa    20200326-1                      OK
python2                    2.7.18-1                        OK
python27                   2.7.18-4                        OK
python27-pip               20.3.3-2                        OK
python27-setuptools        41.2.0-1                        OK
python3                    3.8.6-1                         OK
python36                   3.6.13-1                        OK
python36-pip               21.0-1                          OK
python36-setuptools        51.1.1-1                        OK
python38                   3.8.8-1                         OK
python38-pip               21.0-1                          OK
python38-setuptools        51.1.1-1                        OK
rebase                     4.4.4-1                         OK
rsync                      3.2.3+20200903+git9f9240b-4     OK
run                        1.3.4-2                         OK
sed                        4.4-1                           OK
tar                        1.34-1                          OK
terminfo                   6.1-1.20190727                  OK
terminfo-extra             6.1-1.20190727                  OK
tzcode                     2021a-1                         OK
tzdata                     2021a-1                         OK
util-linux                 2.33.1-2                        OK
vim                        8.2.0486-1                      OK
vim-common                 8.2.0486-1                      OK
vim-minimal                8.2.0486-1                      OK
w32api-headers             8.0.0-1                         OK
w32api-runtime             8.0.0-1                         OK
wget                       1.21.1-1                        OK
which                      2.20-2                          OK
windows-default-manifest   6.4-1                           OK
xxd                        8.2.0486-1                      OK
xz                         5.2.4-1                         OK
zlib                       1.2.11-1                        OK
zlib-devel                 1.2.11-1                        OK
zlib0                      1.2.11-1                        OK
zstd                       1.4.9-1                         OK
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore it

It is due to a failing race at the end of the execution, the fifo is already closed.
It is specific of the Cygwin build